# Problem with lstlisting in beamer

Tags: beamer, verbatim, lstdefinestyle

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedcolumns % for NOT stretching the columns with manual columnbreak
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\lstset{% setup listings 
        language=R,% set programming language 
        basicstyle=\small,% basic font style 
        keywordstyle=\bfseries,% keyword style 
        commentstyle=\ttfamily\itshape,% comment style 
        numbers=left,% display line numbers on the left side 
        numberstyle=\scriptsize,% use small line numbers 
        numbersep=10pt,% space between line numbers and code 
        tabsize=3,% sizes of tabs 
        showstringspaces=false,% do not replace spaces in strings by a certain character 
        captionpos=b,% positioning of the caption below 
        breaklines=true,% automatic line breaking 
        escapeinside={(*}{*)},% escaping to LaTeX 
        fancyvrb=true,% verbatim code is typset by listings 
        extendedchars=false,% prohibit extended chars (chars of codes 128--255) 
        literate={"}{{\texttt{"}}}1{<-}{{$\leftarrow$}}1{<<-}{{$\twoheadleftarrow$}}1 
        {~}{{$\sim$}}1{<=}{{$\le$}}1{>=}{{$\ge$}}1{!=}{{$\neq$}}1{^}{{$^\wedge$}}1,% item to replace, text, length of chars 
        alsoletter={.<-},% becomes a letter 
        alsoother={$},% becomes other 
        otherkeywords={!=, ~, $, *, \&, \%/\%, \%*\%, \%\%, <-, <<-, /},% other keywords 
        deletekeywords={c}% remove keywords 
} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Appendix}[fragile]

%\frametitle{R code:Extracting crimes 2015}
\begin{lstlisting}
datecrimes15 <- which(substr(datecrimes,7,10)==2015)
crimes15 <- crimes[datecrimes15,]
burgl=crimes15[which(crimes15$OFNS_DESC=="BURGLARY"),] Number of burgleries in 2015
ztca <- readShapePoly("ztca/cb_2014_us_zcta510_500k.shp", verbose=TRUE)
ny <- ztca[as.character(ztca$ZCTA5CE10) %in% as.character(zipcode[zipcode$state=="NY",]$zip),]  extract nyzip codes
latlongdata=cbind(robbery$Longitude[which(!is.na(robbery$Longitude & robbery$Latitude))],robbery$Latitude[which(!is.na(robbery$Longitude & robbery$Latitude))]) extract the latitude and longitude of burglaries
pts <- SpatialPoints(as.matrix(latlongdata[,1:2]))
dat <- pts %over% ny #Intersect the coordinates of burglaries with zipcode
zctamap=as.numeric(as.matrix(nycZIPS2$zcta5)) nycZIPS2 is  the  shapedataframe of my zipfile in ny
burgl=cbind(burgl,dat$ZCTA5CE10[-which(is.na(match(burgl$ziprob,zctamap)))])  counting the nomber of burgleries in each nyc zip

\end{lstlisting}



\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I get the error : ! Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.
 
                   \par 
l.249 \end{frame}

Obviusly the line l.249 is different from this ,but it is referred to the last line of this code

Comment: you are loading `listings`-package twice. second, you're giving the frame a title first and then set the `fragile` option. it's `\begin{frame}[fragile]{Appendix}`. the compiler is running wild in the background unable to typeset verbatim content, because of your mixup.

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` or `xcolor` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality. Also `multicol` might be superfluous as beamer has its own environment for columns.